# Create a total of an array of numbers in RubyMotion

Tags: rubymotion

How would i create an array in RubyMotion and then display a total of every number in the array.

For example - Array[1..20] I want to display a total of 1+2+3+4+5+6....up to and including 20. So the total in this case would be 210.

I'm sure this is fairly straight forward but I am relatively new to RubyMotion and arrays bend my minuscule brain.

Cheers for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a loop:

```
numberArray = [1, 2, 3, 4]
total = 0

numberArray.each do |number|
 total += number
end
```

Where the += operator means:

```
x += y
```

is equal to

```
x = x + y
```

Edit :

```
def getSum(my_array)
    total = 0
    my_array.each do |number|
        total += number
    end
    total
end
numberArr = [1,2,3,4]
total = getSum(numberArr)
label.text = "#{total}"
```

I cannot test right now, but it should work.

Comment: Ok. Simple enough but I'm not getting a total, just the array returned. Here's an example of how I'm trying to use it: Set up a method called Total with your code above and then Label.text = "#{Total}" But the label just shows [1, 2, 3, 4]

Comment: I edited my answer, but you should also edit your question with your code, so we can find what's wrong.

Comment: toDateLabel.text = "#{totalToDate}"
       self.view.addSubview toDateLabel
 end
       def getSum(my_array)
       total = 0
      my_array.each do |number|
      total += number
      end
      end
 def totalToDate
 my_array = [1, 2, 3, 4]
 total = getSum(my_array)
 end.......still returns [1,2,3,4] tried various configurations of your code.

Comment: I think you need to specify which value to return from your function. Add the variable name you want to return just before the last end of your function. See the last `total` in my code in the edit.

Comment: final working solution: toDateLabel.text = "#{getSum}"
     self.view.addSubview toDateLabel

 end

 def getSum
    total = 0
    my_array = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    my_array.each do |number|
    total += number
    total1 = total
 end
 total1 = total
 end......One last question - I want to put large arrays and I though you could do array [1..100] for example instead of writing each number individually but that doesn't work. Do you know the correct syntax please?

Answer (score 1):

`(1..20).to_a` create an array of [1, 2, 3, ...., 19, 20] and you can use `Enumerable#inject` for calculation.

```
(1..20).to_a.inject(&:+)
```

You can use this way for Ruby too.

Comment: Not sure how to credit your answer along with Olivers though?? If I tick your then his loses the tick??

Comment: Never mind the tick. I will probably use Watson's answer in the future too.